# Flutter Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this Wrapper Widget

Tags: flutter

After updating/converting a program to null-safety, i'm presented with the following error:

---

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Wrapper Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Wrapper is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

---

The error also points to the "relevant error-causing widget" for me it was my call to my **Wrapper()**, Highlighted below:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Wrapper Wrapper:file:///home/AlphaUser/AndroidStudioProjects/test/lib/main.dart:78:20
```

The stack had more lines I didn't think were relevant. (I can add if needed)

**Current Code in use:**

Main.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/authenticate/test_forgot.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/authenticate/test_login.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/authenticate/test_signup.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/faq_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/review_purchase_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/purchased_products_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/search_products_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/test_postImage.dart';
import 'package:test/wrapper/wrapper.dart';
import "package:provider/provider.dart";
import 'package:test/services/auth.dart';
import 'models/user.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/providers/products_provider.dart';
import 'package:test/providers/shippments_provider.dart';
import 'package:test/providers/orders.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/user_products_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/edit_product_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/product_checkout_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/test_feed.dart';
import 'package:test/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/home/home.dart';
import 'package:test/home/homeUser.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';

void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
     [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
 Stripe.publishableKey =
     'stripe_publishableKey';
 await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application.

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MultiProvider(
     providers: [
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
         create: (ctx) => Shippments(),
       ),
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
         create: (ctx) => Orders(),
       ),
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
         create: (ctx) => Products(),
       ),
     ],
   
     child: StreamProvider<User>.value(
       
       value: AuthService().user,
       initialData: null,
       child: new MaterialApp(
         title: 'Test',
      

         theme: ThemeData(
           primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
           //   accentColor: Colors.green,
         ),

         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         //* Login Options **//
         home: Wrapper(), //***<-- Error points to this line.***
         //home: Home(),  //<-- **Works Fine if I use this instead of Wrapper().** //
         //* Login Options **//
         routes: {
           TestLogin.id: (context) => TestLogin(),
           TestSignup.id: (context) => TestSignup(),
           TestForgot.id: (context) => TestForgot(),
           ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (context) => ProductDetailScreen(),
           UserProductsScreen.routeName: (context) => UserProductsScreen(),
           EditProductScreen.routeName: (context) => EditProductScreen(),
           TestPostImageScreen.routeName: (context) => TestPostImageScreen(),
           ProductCheckoutScreen.routeName: (context) =>
               ProductCheckoutScreen(),
           PurchasedProductsScreen.routeName: (context) =>
               PurchasedProductsScreen(),
           SearchProductsScreen.routeName: (context) => SearchProductsScreen(),
           TestFeed.routeName: (context) => TestFeed(),
           ReviewPurchaseScreen.routeName: (context) => ReviewPurchaseScreen(),
           ProfileScreen.routeName: (context) => ProfileScreen(),
           FAQScreen.routeName: (context) => FAQScreen()
         },
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

wrapper.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:test/home/home.dart';
import 'package:test/home/homeUser.dart';
import 'package:test/models/user.dart' as model;

import '../screens/authenticate/test_login.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  get lists => null;
  bool currentAdmin;
  bool loading = false;


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);


    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _checkUser(user),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        String profile = snapshot.data;
        print("profile!!!: $profile");
        if (profile == 'true') {
          print("Snapshot has data: ${snapshot.data}");
          return Home();
        } else if (profile == 'false') {
          print("Snapshot has no data: ${snapshot.data}");
          return HomeUser();
        } else if (user == null) {
          return TestLogin();
        } else {
          //return CircularProgressIndicator();
          return SpinKitFadingCube(
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 25.0,
          );
        }
        //return null;
      },
    );
  }

  _checkUser(User user) async {
     ...
  } //_checkUser()

}
```

User.dart

```
class User {
  final String uid;

  User({this.uid});
}
```

Just want to add that if I replace Wrapper() with Home() the program works, but that will bypass my "user login/register/forgot password" functionality.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the User Provider and didn't create the user provider yet

add the User Provider in the MultiProvider in main

```
return MultiProvider(
 providers: [
   ChangeNotifierProvider(
     create: (ctx) => Shippments(),
   ),
   ChangeNotifierProvider(
     create: (ctx) => Orders(),
   ),
   ChangeNotifierProvider(
     create: (ctx) => Products(),
   ),
   ChangeNotifierProvider( // add this
     create: (ctx) => User(),
   ),
 ],

 child: StreamProvider<User>.value(
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and input Omar. I made the change you suggested and was faced with another error:

`The raw type was instantiated as 'ChangeNotifierProvider<User*>', and is not regular-bounded (main.dart:58).
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ChangeNotifier'.
Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.  ....etc`

I realized that my original import section for my main was not uploaded properly. I've added  it, along with my "User" file. This my shine more light on the possible solution.

Comment: it seems like you are using User as a normal model class, then why are you using this `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);`? anyway for the above error you have to extend `ChangeNotifier` i.e `class User extends ChangeNotifier {`

Comment: Honestly I've pieced together my test app from several different tutorials and youtube videos. I honestly can't give you a definitive reason why i'm using `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);` in the wrapper.

As far as the fix, that `class User extends ChangeNotifier {` needs to be added in the main?

Comment: in User.dart instead of `class User {` change it to `class User extends ChangeNotifier {`

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested. And i'm able to compile and run the application. 
It appears I've circled back to the original error:
`Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this Wrapper Widget`

Comment: I think Omar's comment around `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);` in my Wrapper.dart may be the key. 
I kept working and it dawned on me (like in other files i've had to deal with) . I have a custom model named User. And now the firebase_auth has a named value User. This was an issue. So I used an `as` prefix on the model becoming `user.dart as model`. I never changed any of the instances in the code to model.user, not sure which ones need to be changed? I think that could be the key. Any Ideas @Omar Hatem?

Comment: first, you have to make different names for them not just use `import as model` like for example `User` and `FirebaseUser`, anyway to fix your issue, you need the class which extends the `ChangeNotifier` to be the one used here `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);` and here `
   ChangeNotifierProvider( // add this
     create: (ctx) => User(),
   ),`